# Highcharts dataGrouping forced and gap

Tags: highcharts

```
dataGrouping: {
    enabled: true,
    forced: true
}
```

imgur.com/oLD44Rm

```
dataGrouping: {
    enabled: true,
    forced: false
}
```

imgur.com/Mo0eE2O

Highcharts large data grupperom well if forced enabled. I found a gap where the data has a large gap. You can leave and forced to remove the gap?

**UPDATE:**

I found this: xAxis.ordinal: false, and series.dataGrouping.forced: true = gap.
http://jsfiddle.net/vj3kynqc/1/

I want to leave xAxis.ordinal: false :)
How to do it without gap the line?

Comment: You can use **Step** in `xAxis: { label {` for insert gap between large data.

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: There is a problem with your data - there are more than one values - y - for the same date - x. With a proper data setting forced to false seems to be resolving the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/sn4bf6L0/